# How to count the number of Strings in localStorage and not the number of characters in it

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how to count the number of Strings present in localStorage and not the number of characters in it. I wrote localStorage.getItem('id').length to see how many numbers of Strings are being saved, but it doesn't count the number of Strings present in *"id"*. It just counts the number of characters present in it. For example, this (**["A","User"]**) are the Strings which are being saved in localStorage and when I use *.length* method, it should show the result as 2 and not 14. Whatever it may be, here are the codes where you can see how I save it in localStorage

```
var newName=document.getElementById('name').value;

if (localStorage.getItem('id') == null) 
{ 
     localStorage.setItem('id', '[]'); 
} 

var old_names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id')); 

 old_names.push(newName); 
    
 localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(old_names));
```

Comment: That would only happen if you don't use `JSON.parse()` before getting the length.

Comment: `old_names.length` should be `2`.

Comment: Local storage stores only strings. As you do it in your code you convert it to an array before updating, and then back to string when storing. So if you want to count strings, convert it to array first and then get the length.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it. I am new to javascript. I saw lot many questions where you can convert it into array but I was unsuccessful

Comment: `let numStringStored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id')).length;`

Comment: @tromgy, thanks for helping me out! It worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sample code

```html
<p id="counter"> names counter : <span>0</span></p>

<p>
  name : <input type="text" id="name" value="">
  <button id="bt-add-name">add</button>
</p>
```

```js
const
  names_Storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names') || '[]')
, e_counter     = document.querySelector('#counter span')
, e_name        = document.querySelector('#name')
  ;

e_counter.textContent = names_Storage.length

document.querySelector('#bt-add-name').onclick = e =>
  {
  let newName = e_name.value.trim()

  if (newName)
    {
    names_Storage.push( newName )
    e_counter.textContent = names_Storage.length
    localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(names_Storage))
    e_name.value = ''
    e_name.focus()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ids = ['1','2','3'] // user ids

//set the ids inside local storage

localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(ids))

//get the ids back from local storage

if('id' in localStorage){
  const ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'))
  console.log(`total ids in local storage ${ids.length}`)
}
```